# Widget update via remoteview Android

Tags: android, android-widget, remoteview

I want my activity "but1" to update the text on my widget button through button in my but1 activity. I've tried and it shows no error but still the widget doesn't updates. Is it something Im missing in manifest file?Moreover the log cat also doesnt show any problem
following is my code in But1.class

```
et1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    Intent in=new Intent();

            Bundle extras=in.getExtras();


            if(extras!=null)
            {
                awID=extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID,AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
            }
                aw=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                    RemoteViews rv=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.activity_main);
                    rv.setTextViewText(R.id.button1, "Mughazf,f,jvnl");
                    aw.updateAppWidget(awID, rv);
                    Intent result=new Intent();
                    result.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, awID);
                    setResult(RESULT_OK,r

esult);
```

and my widget is:

```
@Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);

        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

        for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

 Intent intent = new Intent(context, But1.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);


           RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.activity_main);
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent);

 appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);


        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 4):

Problem should be with the `Widget App ID` . You need to keep remembering the `Widget ID` to update it later.

Your `Widget Provider` onUpdate() method should store the `Widget id` in `shared preference` or `database`

I am using `shared preference` here,

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("private preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 // here i am saving one widget id. change your logic to store all the widget id's
 prefs.edit().putInt("WidgetId",appWidgetId).commit();
```

Then when the `Activity` is launched and button clicked. You can update the `widget layout` like this

First Read the `Widget ID` from `shared Preference`

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences("private preference", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 int awID = prefs.getInt("WidgetId", AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);
```

Then, create the instance of `RemoteView` and set the new text to the `TextView`

```
 RemoteViews rv=new RemoteViews(getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
 rv.setTextViewText(R.id.textView1, "Some one updated Me");
```

Then , get the instance of `AppWidget Manager`

```
  AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
```

And, Finally update the `Widget` with new `RemoteView` `Layout`.

```
  appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(awID, rv);
```

So, awID - is the `Widget Id` what we got from `onUpdate` method.

This should work. Let me know if you see any issue.